# How to prevent a filter from causing a query to run much slower

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following piece of code which runs quickly (<1s):

```
SELECT
    [Policy].[Value] AS [PolicyId]
   ,[Person].[Value] AS [PersonId]
   ,[Person].[Index] AS [PersonIndex]
FROM
    [dbo].[View] AS [Policy]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[ViewPerson] AS [Person] WITH(INDEX([Index])) ON ([Policy].[CollectionId] = [Person].[CollectionId] 
AND [Person].[Name] = 'PersonId' AND [Policy].[Name] = 'PolicyId')
WHERE
    [Policy].[CollectionId] = 10003
    -- AND [Policy].[Value] = [Person].[Value]
```

This will return 2 rows from my database. When I comment out the last line to apply a stronger filter it returns only 1 row from my database, but will take much longer to run (~20s).

Is there a method to reduce the time this query takes to run when a filter is applied to it? Ideally I'd like it to run at the same speed as the original.

Comment: Have you checked the execution plans?

Comment: Why are you forcing SQL Server to use an index?  You should start by checking the explain plan for both queries to find the bottleneck ... and you are in the best position to do this.

Comment: The optimization process of an SQL query starts by checking out the execution plan. I agree with Tim, you shouldn't force SQL Server to use any indexes, instead, let the query optimizer do it's magic.

Comment: if it is possible , Show your table schema, you need to appropriate index on your table.

Comment: @Meta . . . Little advice can be given because you are referencing a view.  No doubt, the definition of that view drives the performance of the overall query.

Comment: Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were told in comments, that forcing the engine to use a special index is - in most cases - not the best idea. The engine is pretty good in finding the best plan and it will work best if you let it go its own route.

Secondly you were told already, that the execution plan is the best place to start. As we do not see any details, the following is pure guessing:

If I get this correctly, your query will use `CollectionId` to filter for one given id (just very few Policy rows). For these rows, the JOIN on a VIEW (we have no idea, what is behind here!) tries to link person rows.

The filter should work against a very reduced set.

Your observations let me assume, that the second line in `WHERE` is dealing with a much larger set. I'm pretty sure, that the filter for `CollectionId=10003` pulls **after** the other filter... The execution plan will show the details...

What you can do:

- Take away the index hint
- Try to add the second line in the WHERE with `AND` to the `ON`-clause of the JOIN.

Something along this:

```
SELECT
    [Policy].[Value] AS [PolicyId]
   ,[Person].[Value] AS [PersonId]
   ,[Person].[Index] AS [PersonIndex]
FROM
    [dbo].[View] AS [Policy]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[ViewPerson] AS [Person]  ON ([Policy].[CollectionId] = [Person].[CollectionId] 
                                               AND [Person].[Name] = 'PersonId' 
                                               AND [Policy].[Name] = 'PolicyId'
                                               AND [Policy].[Value] = [Person].[Value])
WHERE
    [Policy].[CollectionId] = 10003;
```